# Rename a JSON key after a specific pattern

Tags: awk, sed, json

I have a JSON object with the following content:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "id": "77",
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "13"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to look for the KEY "id". And once is found, to start looking for the KEY "answer" and rename it to "answer_id". I want to do that each time it appears.

Expected output:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "id": "77",
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer_id": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "13"
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this so far:

(only solutions with sed or awk)

```
awk   ' { for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {

              if ( $i == "id" )
                  r = 1

              if ( r && $i == "answer")
                  $i = "answer_id" 
                  r = 0           
            }
          }
          1 ' example.json > example2.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ jq '(.quiz[] | select(has("id"))).q1 |= with_entries(select(.key == "answer").key |= "answer_id")' file.json
{
  "quiz": {
    "sport": {
      "id": "77",
      "q1": {
        "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
        "options": [
          "New York Bulls",
          "Huston Rocket"
        ],
        "answer_id": "Huston Rocket"
      }
    },
    "maths": {
      "q1": {
        "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
        "options": [
          "10",
          "13"
        ],
        "answer": "13"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `jq` expression by itself:

```
(.quiz[] | select(has("id"))).q1 |=
    with_entries(select(.key == "answer").key |= "answer_id")
```

[This uses `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to locate the correct `.quiz` entry, which is the one that has an `id` key.

For that entry, it picks out the `q1` key's value (a JSON object), and renames that object's `answer` key into `answer_id`.  The renaming of the key is done using `with_entries()`, which transforms both the keys and values of an object into modifiable values, and then back again.  Inside `with_entries()`, we select the key we want to rename and simply rename it.

I opted for using a proper JSON parser rather than trying to use `awk` or some other tool that isn't really useful for parsing structured document formats.  Note that your example document might have looked like

```json
{"quiz":{"sport":{"id":"77","q1":{"question":"Which one is correct team name in NBA?","options":["New York Bulls","Huston Rocket"],"answer":"Huston Rocket"}},"maths":{"q1":{"question":"5 + 7 = ?","options":["10","13"],"answer":"13"}}}}
```

which is a valid JSON document that is *equivalent* to the document in the question.  The `jq` tool would have parsed them both equivalently and produced the same result.